# Fragment Manager does not work in Android studio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I am new to Kotlin and fragments, and I am facing an issue. I'm trying to create a button that, when clicked, will navigate to a new fragment, the **CreateNoteFragment**. For some reason that I can't understand, it doesn't recognize the *supportFragmentManager *command. Do I need to add any libraries, or is the problem elsewhere? Thank you.

Here is my code in **main activity**

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fabBtCreateNote = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fubBtCreateNote)
        fabBtCreateNote.setOnClickListener {
            val createNoteFragment = CreateNoteFragment()
            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, createNoteFragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null) // Προσθήκη του Fragment στο back stack
            transaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

I tried to add some libraries but it didn't work. What should I do ?

Comment: There is no variable named `supportFragmentManager` in your code

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause `supportFragmentManager` is not something assignable, but it's already present, so your code should look something like this:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.fragment_container, CreateNoteFragment.newInstance())
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit()
```

Remember to call `CreateNoteFragment()` and not `createNoteFragment` as you need to use the companion object to istantiate the fragment.

Please let me know if this solved your problem, if not, update your question providing more detailed code about your fragment, happy coding!

**EDIT**

Sorry my bad, it was **CreateNoteFragment.newInstance()** and not **CreateNoteFragment()**.

(This is assuming you have the `newInstance()` method in your `companion object` inside of your `CreateNoteFragment`)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understood what was my mistake and changed my code but I have an error. I am sure it is my mistake again I am trying my best but I don t think that I have understand it correctly. 
 `fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.fragment_container, CreateNoteFragment())
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit() `  The error is now in **R.id.fragment_container** and **CreateNoteFragment()** . What fragment_container do exactly?

Comment: Can you update your question with the error ?

Comment: Unresolved reference: fragment_container 
Type mismatch: inferred type is CreateNoteFragment but Fragment! was expected

Comment: Have you solved ? @GeorgeKazz